# How to vertically clip text so it doesn't split a line in the middle

Tags: css, text

I was wondering if there is some css/js magic that can prevent text from splitting vertically in the middle of a line. I'm using overflow:hidden in the below example. The text is not static ... it is rich-text entered by a user so I do not have control over the formatting.

[image: the third line of text is clipped in the middle]

i would like it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Asked a few times and there doesn't appear to be a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220812/css-can-you-prevent-overflow-hidden-from-cutting-off-the-last-line-of-text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616074/avoid-an-element-from-being-cut-off-when-they-are-inside-a-overflow-hidden-el

Comment: What is your exact HTML and CSS? Perhaps there's no "magic" solution but there are contextual ones.

Comment: Do you set a fixed height on that element? How about doing a `min-height` and then letting it expand vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible example solution:

```
.dataTable td {
  /* essential */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* for good looks */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

via http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis

**Solution example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Fpq2/

This should at least provide a starting point.

Also, here are some additional possible solutions:

- http://www.mobify.com/dev/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css
- http://softwareas.com/pure-css-solution-to-avoid-cutting-off-text

Comment: though i wasn't able to use this to specifically fix my problem, the second link (softwareas.com) gave a nice solution that will work for me in other projects. in short it fades the text out at the bottom using a mask. that would be good enough for most of my uses. thanks

Comment: The fade out method descibed by @DonDickinson above can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertofrega/LkYjs/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use wrapper div and multi-column css:

```
.wrapper {
    -webkit-column-width: 150px; //You can't use 100%
    column-width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Solution example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Fpq2/9/